# Redirect if Database has a certain value

Tags: php, mysql, database

Okay, so, the php page is already connected to the database.

Let's say we have a database, and within that database there is a table called Users.

The users table has two columns. Username and Voted.

I want a php query that says if "Username" has a "0" on Voted, it redirects them to a certain page. If voted has "1" it doesn't redirect them and they begin to go along with their day.

Comment: *I want a php query that... redirects them* A query doesn't redirect someone. What is your code?

Comment: it would look something like this,
<php if username = $Username + voted = 0 --> http://google.com

Comment: Note: There is no `php query` only `MYSQL Queries` and you have too do SQL action first to check for the value, then using `header('Location:xxx')` with PHP to move on.

Comment: JustOnUnderMillions how would it look like, I haven't done MYSQL queries in a very long time.

Comment: Some like `SELECT Voted FROM users WHERE Username='Username'`

Comment: Okay so that has selected the Voted column, so what would be next? IF Voted = "0'    how do i make that redirect to a website?

Comment: @omarisgod see next answer. Very long time no PHP/SQL ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the username has 0 on voted by using SQL syntax

If, the condition is true use header() like:

```
$voted = // Get your value from database connection
if ($voted == 0) {
    header("Location: somewhere/page");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much.

Comment: My pleasure,,, and be sure to select as answer so it can be helpful for others.